# unable to call fetch on a backbone model

Tags: backbone.js

In the function `jsonRequest` below, I can log `this.model` to the console, but I can't call `this.model.fetch()`, which I thought was the appropriate way to make a request to my server (at `localhost:8080/jsonapi`). The error it gives me is can't call `fetch` of undefined. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the code below?

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      url: 'jsonapi',
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#blahblah',
        initialize: function(){

        },
        events: {
                'click #start' : 'callJsonRequest',

        },
        callJsonRequest: function(){
              setInterval(this.jsonRequest, 1000);
        }, 

        jsonRequest: function(){
                         console.log("jsonrequest", this.model); //this logs the model
                         this.model.fetch();
                     },

  });

    window.myModel = new MyModel();
    window.startStop = new StartView({model: myModel});
```

Comment: You likely need to use `bind` to make sure `this` is the context of your View object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to use `bind` to make sure `this` is the context of your View object.

As you mentioned in the comments, you can do:

```
setInterval(this.jsonRequest.bind(this), 1000);
```